# How to count leafs that are before a given node in a tree?

Tags: algorithm, tree

How would you implement a function that returns the number of leafs that are found before a given element in that tree ? Assuming you are reading the tree from left to right ?

I found away to do it but it's not very straightforward and uses Exceptions mechanism, I think there might be an elegant way to do it ?

Comment: May you post some example? what do you mean by "found before a given element"? duplicates are possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you could just dfs the tree, count the leafs, save it to every node. like

```
int count;

void dfs(int x){
    dfs(x->left);
    leafBefore[x] = count;
    if (x is leaf) count += 1;
    dfs(x->right);
}

count = 0;
dfs(root);
```